# Can the geodesic flow be preserved by an inhomogeneous rescaling of a cross section?

Tags: dg.differential-geometry

Let $M$ be a compact Riemannian manifold with metric $g$ and associated Riemannian volume $\nu$ and [geodesic flow](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Geodesic#Geodesic_flow) $G_t : UTM \rightarrow UTM$, where the [unit tangent bundle](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Unit_tangent_bundle) is indicated. Let $X_j \subset UTM$ for $1 \le j \le n$ be open disjoint codimension one submanifolds transversal to $G_t$, i.e., local cross sections ([a global cross section does not exist](http://books.google.com/books?id=1K66IrjWbgwC&lpg=PP1&ots=EPHHQe4_Ip&dq=Geodesic%2520%25EF%25AC%2582ows&pg=PA49#v=onepage&q=lemma%25202.52&f=false)).

> Is it possible to choose a metric $g'$
>   on $M$ with geodesic flow $G'_t = G_t$
>   and $\nu'_1(X_j) \equiv 1$?

NB. Here $\nu'_1$ denotes the induced codimension one [relative] measure on $UTM$.

This question was prompted by a helpful comment to [this one](https://mathoverflow.net/questions/26834/).

Comment: What is the definition of $\nu_1'$? Is it the restriction of the metric to $X_j$? in that case, I don't know why should $g$ be changed, do you know an example where $g$ does not work?

Comment: $\nu_1'$ is the restriction of the Riemannian measure induced by $g'$. The idea is to tweak stuff transversal to the flow to achieve local cross sections with uniform induced measure.

Comment: Ok, so you want the local cross section to be connected? Otherwise you can take "enough" different small cross sections in order to get as much measure as you like.  

For 3-dimensional flows which are Anosov geodesic flows, you can look at Fried's work (he constructs "almost"-global cross sections) D. FRIED: Transitive Anosov flows and pseudo-Anosov maps, Topology 22,3 (1983) (sorry I couldn't make an hyperlink, but google takes you there)

Comment: I want the local cross sections to be generic and given in advance, and to then manipulate the metric in order to uniformize their measures while preserving the geodesic flow.

Comment: Thanks. Finally understood, nice question. Sorry (I don't have an answer).

Comment: http://books.google.com/books?id=mz-GkuFS9FgC&pg=PA92&lpg=PA92

Answer (score 2):

Unless I misunderstand this reference<sup>*</sup> after a cursory look, it appears that the answer is generally no: ["geodesic conjugacy" often implies isometry.](http://books.google.com/books?id=njIG5AqcQ2YC&pg=PA217)

---

<sup>*</sup> and anways, why is it that references seem so much easier to find once I've posted a question on MO?